# Why is my SSD performance so poor?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I just installed Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit to a new Samsung 850 Pro 256 GB SSD on a system with an Asus Sabertooth P67 motherboard and 16 GB of RAM. The drive is plugged into a 6 Gbps Intel port and the UEFI is set to AHCI for the Intel SATA ports. Windows is up to date and the Intel drivers are all the latest drivers that I can find, although the SATA AHCI Controller driver is version 10.5.0.1026 from 4/26/2011 as it was downloaded from Asus and I could not find a more recent driver from Intel.

Here are the Samsung Magician benchmark results:
[image]
Note that I have performed the disk and OS optimizations.

I could live with the sequential speeds, but the IOPS are just pathetic compared the drive's capability. I do have TrueCrypt 7.1a with full disk encryption, but given that the system has hardware AES, TrueCrypt reports throughput benchmark of 3.4 Gbps, so I'm not clear that this would affect anything.

Comment: What do you expect the numbers to me?  Have you consulted the OS optimization section of Magician?

Comment: @Ramhound Something better than 8% or 18% of capacity? I stated in the question that OS and disk optimization has already been performed.

Comment: TrueCrypt comes at a cost: IO is serialized. This is, what you see in the RIOPS, where parallel execution is much more of an issue than with sequential speeds.

Comment: @EugenRieck Do you have any links to explain this?

Comment: Many things influence performance, especially in a system using encryption. This may help explain some http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61089/can-truecrypt-encrypt-ssds-without-performance-problems

Comment: @Paul Read http://media-addicted.de/truecrypt-und-ssd-performance-samsung-ssd-830/1159/ (sorry, german - I am from Europe) for -87,8% performance in read RIOPS. The main issue seems to be, that due to the pseudo-random pattern of empty space, the SSD garbage collection is slower by orders of magnitude. Try leaving 20-25% of the SSD empty, running `blocktim` over it.

Comment: @EugenRieck The article does not state which version of TrueCrypt is used. The last version released contained fixes related to wear-leveling and other articles I've found state that there is no longer any performance or durability benefit to leaving the empty space, but there is a hit to the effectiveness of the encryption.